# cudaMemcpy2D causing seg fault

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to allocate and initialize a 2D array using *cudaMallocPitch()* and *cudaMemcpy2D()*. I have been able to allocate several arrays using the previous APIs however there is a particular array that keeps causing my program to seg fault.

My code is,

```
int size = totalPat * trainingSize * wordSize; // 65 * 672 * 15
char ** h_pattern = (char**) malloc((size_t) 40 * sizeof(char));

for(int = 0; i < 40; i++){
   h_pattern[i] = (char*) malloc((size_t) size * sizeof(char));
   fill_n(h_pattern[i], size, '\0');
 }

 char * d_pattern;
 size_t dpitch;
 size_t spitch = size * sizeof(char);

 cudaMallocPitch(&d_patterns, &dpitch, spitch, 40));
 cudaMemcpy2D(d_pattern, dpitch, h_pattern, spitch, spitch, 40, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

I used cuda-gdb to debug my program and locate the problem and it keeps seg faulting in *cudaMemcpy2D()*. Backtrace gives the following output,

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff501dd00 in cudbgGetAPIVersion () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
(cuda-gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff501dd00 in cudbgGetAPIVersion () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff4efc68e in cuMemGetAttribute_v2 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff4f0cc7f in cuMemGetAttribute_v2 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff4efd7f1 in cuMemGetAttribute_v2 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff4e6b322 in cuMemGetAttribute_v2 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff4e74b38 in cuMemGetAttribute_v2 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff4e4d92a in cuMemcpy2DUnaligned_v2 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
#7  0x000000000045bc5d in cudart::driverHelper::memcpy2DPtr(char*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, cudaMemcpyKind, CUstream_st*, bool, bool) ()
#8  0x0000000000435039 in cudart::cudaApiMemcpy2DCommon(void*, unsigned long, void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, cudaMemcpyKind, bool) ()
#9  0x00000000004350f8 in cudart::cudaApiMemcpy2D(void*, unsigned long, void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, cudaMemcpyKind) ()
#10 0x0000000000462073 in cudaMemcpy2D ()
```

In devtalk forum there was question regarding pitch limits where *cudaMemcpy2D()* failed with pitch size greater than 2^18 however this question was from 2007 and I would assume this limit no longer exists. Also in the documentation there is a mention that if dpitch or spitch exceeds the maximum allowed *cudaMemcpy2D()* returns an error but they don't tell what is the maximum allowed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cudaMemcpy2D requires an underlying contiguous allocation and it requires that the host data you pass to it be referenceable by a single pointer (*) not a double pointer.  This is the source of your seg fault.  You can rectify this fairly simply by allocating your `h_pattern` array with a single large `malloc` allocation.  If you want, you can still reference it using doubly-subscripted access in host code using a methodology like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702573/simple-cuda-test-always-fails-with-an-illegal-memory-access-was-encountered-er/25702996#25702996)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a reason on why doesn't the compiler marks this as an error? Using double pointer instead of single. Additionally, is there maximum pitch allowed? Because when I try to allocate 10kB by 40 (width * height) of type float, the corresponding pitch is almost 900 thousand.

Comment: I believe it is because the function prototype for `cudaMemcpy2D` expects a `void*` in this parameter, and I believe that [C++ allows implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) of a pointer  to a `void*` under some circumstances.  Such conversions do not carry an error or warning.  C++ is more restrictive than C in general in terms of implicit conversion, but I believe this particular one (any pointer to `void*`) is allowed, implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is trying to copy `40 * size` bytes data of the type `char` to a 40-byte host memory space of the type `char*`.

Instead you need to malloc a linear memory space for all 40 patterns on the host like:

```
char* h_pattern;
h_pattern = (char*) malloc((size_t) 40* size * sizeof(char));
```